# Tableau - Building a calculated field based on a filtered date range

Tags: date, tableau-api, calculated-field

I need to build a calculation that takes into account whether or not someone checks on a day in Tableau. Currently using Tableau 10.0.5.

For instance, say I have the following data

Date    Amount
1-Oct   100
1-Oct   120
2-Oct   150
3-Oct   200
4-Oct   250
5-Oct   500

I need a way to calculate the total amount for the days that are checked in a filter. So, if a user selected Oct 1 to Oct 3, the amount would be $570. Any ideas on how to make this happen are appreciated.

I know how much we all love to work with dates in Tableau! :-)

Comment: I recently purchased a tool that will help us to decide whether to use Tableau for our reporting. [Amazon link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Home-Garden-Store/BUTTON-SOUND-MACHINE-NOVELTY-OFFICE-LARGE-PRANKS/B01C4EGOWC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1484862164&sr=8-1&keywords=no+button)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not showing dates in your viz then simply ***sum([Amount])*** will give you the sum of amount for selected dates.
In case you want to show individual dates and sum of sales across all dates you will have to use Level of Detail Expression
***{ EXCLUDE [Date]:SUM([Amount])}***
[Here is the URL for Example](https://public.tableau.com/profile/publish/Solution_1/WithDates#!/publish-confirm)